werkzeug.routing.exceptions.WebsocketMismatch
I have setuupped server for twilio, where a user will call a twilio number and we can able to capture the stream.but i am getting a error regarding websocket mismatch.
I am unable to figure it out how to resolve it.
import base64
import json

from flask import Flask, request
from flask_sockets import Sockets
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse, Connect
from twilio.rest import Client

HTTP_SERVER_PORT = 8080

account_sid = ""
auth_token = ""

app = Flask(__name__)
sockets = Sockets(app)

twilio_client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

@app.route('/call', methods=['POST'])
def twilio_webhook():
    response = VoiceResponse()
    connect = Connect()
    connect.stream(url=f'wss://{request.host}/media')
    response.append(connect)
    response.say('You are now connected to the stream!')
    print(f'Incoming call from {request.form["From"]}')
    return str(response), 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}

def on_transcription_response(response):
    if not response.results:
        return

    result = response.results[0]
    if not result.alternatives:
        return

    transcription = result.alternatives[0].transcript
    print("Transcription: " + transcription)

@sockets.route("/media")
def transcript(ws):
    print("WS connection opened")
    while not ws.closed:
        message = ws.receive()
        if message is None:
            print(len(message))
            break

        data = json.loads(message)
        if data["event"] in ("connected", "start"):
            print(f"Media WS: Received event '{data['event']}': {message}")
            continue
        if data["event"] == "media":
            media = data["media"]
            chunk = base64.b64decode(media["payload"])
            print("yes media is there and its length is ", len(chunk))
        if data["event"] == "stop":
            print(f"Media WS: Received event 'stop': {message}")
            print("Stopping...")
            break

    print("WS connection closed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from gevent import pywsgi
    from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler

    server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(
        ("", HTTP_SERVER_PORT), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler
    )
    print("Server listening on: http://localhost:" + str(HTTP_SERVER_PORT))
    server.serve_forever()

d.
  File "c:\Kunal\Projects\RiDiv\EVA\AsstProject\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing\map.py", line 627, in match
    raise WebsocketMismatch() from None
werkzeug.routing.exceptions.WebsocketMismatch: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
    raise WebsocketMismatch() from None
werkzeug.routing.exceptions.WebsocketMismatch: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
d.
2024-07-21T15:08:47Z {'REMOTE_ADDR': '::1', 'REMOTE_PORT': '47455', 'HTTP_HOST': '8c56-223-185-39-94.ngrok-free.app', (hidden keys: 29)} failed with WebsocketMismatch

I tried to add a rule, but the exact way i didnt get , please guide me how can i resolve this

i'm also getting this. i wonder why?
